# xslt transformation from xhtml to custom xml

Tags: php, xml, xslt

For a custom application I need to transform xhtml to (custom) xml. After some experimentation I decided to give php5's XSLT functionality a try, but so far I'm unable to transform nested p tags to their xml equivalent.

Basicly we have code like this:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<ol>
   <li><p>Some more text</p></li>
   ..
</ol>
```

This needs to be transformed to:

```
<par>Some text</par>
<list>
  <li><par>Some more text</par></li>
  ..
</list>
```

The real problem is: I need to include inline tags, so xsl:value-of is no option and instead I use xsl:copy-of. So far I have templates for ol|ul and p and the result is this:

```
<par>Some text</par>
<list>
  <li><p>Some more text</p></li>
  ..
</list>
```

Anybody some tips how to achieve what I really want just by using a more complex xslt?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:element name="par">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <xsl:element name="list">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <xsl:template match="li">
        <xsl:element name="li">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ============================================== -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This does get me a bit further, however is seems inline elements are lost this way?

Comment: You can't have it both ways. If you ask for a copy, no further processing occurs. What you should do is create a default template that copies the name of the element, and continues processing, and override that for the elements you're changing.

Comment: What do you mean by "inline elements"?

Comment: Do you mean that if the "p" tag is embedded in a "li" tag, it is NOT to be converted to "par"?

Comment: I mean stuff like this: <p><strong>Bold text</strong> some more text</p>

However simply adding more templates for all child and inline elements , seems a good solution :)

Comment: If you want to preserve those other elements and don't want to create a template for every single combination, then add this identity transform template to the XSLT that @dacracot proposed: `   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>`

Answer (score 1):

If you start with the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), the general pattern for transforming elements with one name into elements of another is this:

```
<xsl:template match="old_name">
   <new_name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </new_name>
</xsl:template>
```

Two things of note:

1. Generally, unless you know for certain that the element you're transforming has no attributes (or you actively intend to strip off the attributes), you should use the `select` attribute shown; don't just use `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.  Attributes aren't child nodes, and thus applying templates without a `select` attribute doesn't apply templates to them.
2. Unless you really enjoy typing, there is almost never a reason to use `<xsl:element>`.  The exception is when you're generating the output element's name programmatically.

Which, actually, you could do if you wanted to get all fancy-shmancy:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:variable name="new_name">
      <xsl:when test="name()='p'>par</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='ol'>list</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="name()='li'>item</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:element name="{$new_name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 (and +1 more, if I could) - Note that `test="name()='p'` will not work *unless* the XSL document is in the same default namespace as the XHTML input. One could use `local-name()` instead, but declaring the XHMTL namespace with a prefix and changing to `test="name()='xhtml:p'` is the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested [`<xsl:element>`](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_element.asp) tags to output inline tags as you propose.

Something like:

```
<xsl:element name="li">
  <xsl:element name="p">
   some text
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example? Do I need to put this inside of a template and is the result static or dynamic (as in can I 'recycle' arbitrary content and inline tags or does it simply output a fixed set of elements and content)?